# When the image of an idempotent endomorphism is maximal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

Let $M$ be a module and let $e$ be an idempotent element in $End(M)$. Suppose that the image of $e$ is a maximal submodule of $M$. Is it true that the left ideal generated by $e$ is a maximal ideal of $End(M)$?

Comment: Can you add anything at all to your problem statement?  It would be helpful to know where you're at.